# How to Rename the Admin Menu From WordPress theme files or plugin?

Tags: wordpress, themes

[image]

I want to change the blue marked portfolio menu to Course. Basically I want to change---
Portfolios--->> Courses
Add New Portfolio -->> Add New Course

And When I add click on add new portfolio it is show add new portfolio. Instead of this I want to show add new course and course setting in the marked area.

I just want to edit it from theme file but unable find it out. Help..me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try *add_filter( 'post_type_labels_post', 'rename_labels' )* hook

```
add_filter( 'post_type_labels_post', 'rename_labels' );
function rename_labels($labels){
  $labels->Portfolio='Course';
  return $labels;   
}
```

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/9211/changing-admin-menu-labels

Comment: where to add these code?

Comment: you can add it to the functions.php file of your theme or to a plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Which plugin you have used for Adding Portfolios?

You can customize it by editing theme/plugin templates.

You will see admin folder which will contain all these files. These name can also be stored in variables so I can't respond to your query without access to FTP.

Comment: please be more specific in your answer and use the comment function under the question